# java Send exception with completable Future

Tags: java, validation, exception, completable-future

I have to send an exception if a field is empty in a CompletableFuture code:

```
 public CompletableFuture<ChildDTO> findChild(@NotEmpty String id) {
            return ChildRepository.findAsyncById(id)
                    .thenApply(optionalChild -> optionalChild
                            .map(Child -> ObjectMapperUtils.map(Child, ChildDTO.class))
                            .orElseThrow(CurrentDataNotFoundException::new));
 }
```

The idea is if the child have a field empty in this case lastName, I have to throw a custom exception, I am not pretty sure how can I achieve this.

My idea is to use the thenAccept method and send the exception just like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<ChildDTO> findChild(@NotEmpty String id) {
                return ChildRepository.findAsyncById(id)
                        .thenApply(optionalChild -> optionalChild
                                .map(Child -> ObjectMapperUtils.map(Child, ChildDTO.class))
                                .orElseThrow(CurrentDataNotFoundException::new))
     }.thenAccept{
            ........................

     }

   ObjectMapperUtils Code: 

   public static <S, D> D map(final S entityToMap, Class<D> expectedClass) {
        return modelMapper.map(entityToMap, expectedClass);
    }


public class ChildDTO {
    @NotEmpty
    private String id;
    @PassengerIdConstraint
    private String ownerId;
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    @ChildAgeConstraint
    private Integer age;
    @NotNull
    private Gender gender;
    @NotEmpty
    private String language;
```

I have to evaluate if lastName is empty from the db I have to throw an exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's wrong with your code? what does this method `ObjectMapperUtils` do?

Comment: @Deadpool Nothing wrong I just need to send an exception if for example the optionalChild.lastname is Empty. I am not sure how can I throw a new custom Exception if this field is empty.

Comment: can you show the `ChildDTO` and also can you show the `ObjectMapperUtils` class, if the field is present you have to return object else throw exception right?

Comment: @Deadpool the ObjectMapperUtils.map transform from childDTO to child. The idea is if the child has a field with empty value I have to throw an exception.

Comment: @Deadpool I added the code you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My below approach is by assuming `findAsyncById` method returns `CompletableFuture<Optional<ChildDTO>>`. so you can use the filter to check `lastName` is empty or not, if empty throw exception using `orElseThrow`

```
public CompletableFuture<ChildDTO> findChild(@NotEmpty String id) {
            return ChildRepository.findAsyncById(id)
                    .thenApply(optionalChild -> optionalChild
                            .map(Child -> ObjectMapperUtils.map(Child, ChildDTO.class))
                             // If child last name is empty then return empty optional
                            .filter(child->!child.getLastName())   
                             // If optional is empty then throw exception
                            .orElseThrow(CurrentDataNotFoundException::new))
```